# Can not "pip install smtpd"

Tags: python, smtpd

I have missing module and I don't know how do I install this. Is there a newer version? I want to do something like: `python3.6 -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025`

Comment: You can download the package and just `python setup.py install` from the directory root look [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smtpd-tls/0.1)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtpd.html#smtpd.SMTPServer ..

Answer (score 0):

**Try This.. For Python: 3.6**

> From pip install Smtpd

```
pip install smtpd-tls
```

> install the latest version of a module and its dependencies from the
>   Python Packaging

```
python -m pip install SomePackage
```

> For Specific Version and Minimum Version Install

```
python -m pip install SomePackage==3.6.1    # specific version
python -m pip install "SomePackage>=1.0.4"  # minimum version
```

For More Read This :  https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html

For Smtpd Read This :  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smtpd-tls/0.1

Comment: why smtpd-tls ? I tired your solution for smtpd but still ca not find

Comment: added implicit tls

Comment: actually its for older version